# Convert Targets direct to Account in SugarCRM

Tags: target, sugarcrm, account

Anyway to convert Targets directly to Accounts?

I know the process is to have Target convert to Leads and then only convert Lead to Account.
But there are some businesses logics changed, when user in the Account details page, they always can see the Campaign activities at the Sub Panel of Campaign.

How to bypass the conversion and link the Account to Target?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First, let's understand how it works currently. `/modules/Prospects/metadata/detailviewdefs.php` contains the definitions for the Prospect (Target) detail view, including that "Convert Target" button. The button is defined this way:

```
array(
  'customCode' => '<input title="{$MOD.LBL_CONVERT_BUTTON_TITLE}" class="button" onclick="this.form.return_module.value=\'Prospects\'; this.form.return_action.value=\'DetailView\'; this.form.return_id.value=\'{$fields.id.value}\';this.form.module.value=\'Leads\';this.form.action.value=\'EditView\';" type="submit" name="CONVERT_LEAD_BTN" value="{$MOD.LBL_CONVERT_BUTTON_LABEL}"/>',
  'sugar_html' => array(
    'type' => 'submit',
    'value' => '{$MOD.LBL_CONVERT_BUTTON_LABEL}',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
      'class' => 'button',
      'name' => 'CONVERT_LEAD_BTN',
      'id' => 'convert_target_button',
      'title' => '{$MOD.LBL_CONVERT_BUTTON_TITLE}',
      'onclick' => 'this.form.return_module.value=\'Prospects\'; this.form.return_action.value=\'DetailView\'; this.form.return_id.value=\'{$fields.id.value}\';this.form.module.value=\'Leads\';this.form.action.value=\'EditView\';',
    ),
  )
),
```

Note that the first array param customCode is deprecated in 6.5 and forward, so don't worry about that. Focus on sugar_html and specifically that onclick definition. This is defining the values of form.module.value and form.action.value. Suppose instead of populating a new Lead's EditView we feed that into a custom action?

(As an aside, you may notice that in the generated form the onclick attribute is converted heavily such that "this.form" is converted to something like `var _form = document.form; _form.return_module=\'yada yada\'` -- this doesn't matter so long as you stick with the conventions.)

*Don't modify anything in /modules/* Instead, from the root of your SugarCRM directory, you can `cp --parents modules/Prospects/metadata/detailviewdefs.php custom` which will create the path and file /custom/modules/Prospects/metadata/detailviewdefs.php. Dig into this and modify that button so that the onclick parameter reads something like this:

```
'onclick' => 'this.form.return_module.value=\'Prospects\'; this.form.return_action.value=\'DetailView\'; this.form.return_id.value=\'{$fields.id.value}\';this.form.module.value=\'Accounts\';this.form.action.value=\'CustomAccountCreator\';',
```

I've adjusted the module and action values there to point to Accounts instead of Leads, and to a new action we're going to dream up called "CustomAccountCreator." Next step is to create that action. The old school (less best practice but much easier) way of doing so is to create a file at `custom/modules/Accounts/CustomAccountCreator.php` and you could populate it with something like this:

```
<?php
$target = BeanFactory::getBean($_REQUEST['return_id']);
$account = new Account();
$account->name = $target->account_name;
$account->phone_office = $target->phone_work;
$account->save();
```

Obviously that's highly simplified, You'll want more fields than that, and you should do some error checking to make sure the $target loads correctly. You could also use some fields to create a new Contact record and relate the Contact and Account if you want.

With all files and code in place, you'll need to do a Repair & Rebuild to see the changes.

Comment: alright, I will try your solution next week. Update you soon!